# Callback function of Process.on Sigterm no longer called after Updating from Node 18 to Node 20.10.0

Tags: javascript, node.js

I run a node app in a docker container. When I stopped the container under Node 18 the callback function of process.on('SIGTERM', ...) was executed. After updating to Node 20.10 the function is no longer called. Can anyone tell me what is the reason and how to fix it?

```
const process = require('process');
...
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Process.on: SIGTERM');
   ...
 });
```

I could't find any information in the web so I asked Google Bard. It responded that here https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.0.0 would be the follwing information be written:

> The process.on() method now defers execution of the listener callback
> until the next event loop iteration. This change ensures that the
> callback is always executed in a consistent order, regardless of when
> the event is emitted.

And hence it suggested to wrap the code into setTimeout like this

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Process.on: SIGTERM');
    ...
  }, 0);
});
```

But it doesn't work. The code in the callback function is still not being executed. I also did not find Google Bards quote in the provided url. Maybe it made that up.

Comment: Yeah if the callback isn't executed, putting a `setTimeout` in that callback won't achieve anything. Bard is talking nonsense.